# Создать триггеры отслеживающие удаление\ вставку

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Есть 2 таблицы

```
db.execSQL("Create table STUDGROUPS (" + BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, faculty text, course int, name text, head text," +
                "constraint name_u unique (name) on conflict abort);");
db.execSQL("Create table Students (" + BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, name text, IDGROUP int," +
                "constraint idgroup_fk foreign key(IDGROUP) references STUDGROUPS(_id) on delete cascade on update cascade);");
```

В группе не должно быть больше 6 студентов и меньше 3, т.е. нужно запреть вставку, если есть с одинаковым id группы 6 студентов и удаление, есть оно приведет к нахождению в группе меньше 3 человек.

Важным условием является сохранение каскада. Поэтому, при удалении студента необходимо проверить, удалена ли его группа. Если да, то ограничения на меньше 3 снимаются и студент удаляется, если нет, то удаление запрещаем.

Помогите написать такие триггеры.Help!

Answer (score 1):

```
create trigger prevent_big_groups before insert on students
begin
    select case when (
        select count(*) from students where idgroup = NEW.idgroup
    ) = 5 then raise(ABORT, 'Too much students in the group') end;
end;

create trigger prevent_small_groups before delete on students
begin
    select case when (
        select count(*) from students where idgroup = OLD.idgroup
    ) = 3 then raise(ABORT, 'Not enough students in the group') end
    from studgroups where id = OLD.idgroup;
end;
```